# how to use value of one table in another table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$voter=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voter where voter_id='$_SESSION[voter_id]'")
or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
$state = $row['state'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE candidate_region = '$state'")
  or die(" There are no records at the moment ... \n");
```

?>
Above code had two separate table voter and candidate.
What I want is that  after selecting state from table voter i.e $state  I want to use in candidate.
Which i have done above in code but i am not getting value from $state in candidate table.

Comment: post your both tabel with expected output

Comment: You can do this in a single query, but the `mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used.  Use `mysqli_query` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Or you can use left join for this

Comment: use JOIN query `SELECT * FROM voter, Candidates where candidate_region = state  AND voter_id='$_SESSION[voter_id]'`